# How to set the OpenApi operationId with .NET 8 MapIdentityApi

Tags: .net, openapi

**Is there an option to dynamically set the OperationId for paths that are generated by MapIdentityApi in .NET 8?**

I noticed that I can set the operation ID using `WithOpenApi`, but it appears to work only for setting it statically. Or is there a way to dynamically set the operation ID using WithOpenApi?:

```
app.MapGroup("/auth").MapIdentityApi<User>().WithOpenApi(operation => new OpenApiOperation(operation)
{
    // Sets it to a static value
    OperationId = "Test"
});
```

My goal would be to end up with Operation IDs similar to this:

```
"paths": {
    "/auth/register": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "Auth_Register_Post",
      }
    },
    "/auth/login": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "Auth_Login_Post",
      }
    },
    "/auth/refresh": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "Auth_Refresh_Post",
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution that I've found is to add a `SwaggerOperationIdFilter` that implements the `IOperationFilter` interface to the `AddSwaggerGen`. This filter is used to dynamically set the OperationId for Swagger operations.

### Program.cs (Startup)

Register the SwaggerOperationIdFilter as an operation filter during the Swagger generation process.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
  options.OperationFilter<SwaggerOperationIdFilter>();
  // ... other SwaggerGen configurations
}
```

### Implementation of SwaggerOperationIdFilter.cs

```
public class SwaggerOperationIdFilter : IOperationFilter
{
  public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
  {
    // Check if it's a MapIdentityApi action
    if (context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor is not ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)
    {
      var relativePath = context.ApiDescription.RelativePath ?? "";
      operation.OperationId = $"{GenerateOperationIdBaseString(relativePath)}_{context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod}";
      return;
    }

    // For other controller actions, set OperationId based on controller and action names
    operation.OperationId = $"{controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName}_{controllerActionDescriptor.ActionName}_{context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod}";
  }

  // Helper Method to extract the controller and the action name
  private static string GenerateOperationIdBaseString(string inputString)
  {
    var input = inputString.Split('/');
    if (input.Length == 0)
    {
      return string.Empty;
    }

    var controllerName = input[0].FirstCharToUpper();
    var actionName = string.Join("", input.Skip(1).Select(word => word.FirstCharToUpper()));
        
    return $"{controllerName}_{actionName}";
  }
}
```